# Best way to fetch data from Mysql Database for big hierarchy through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I have a data hierarchy like this:

```
Country
-President // A Person
--Central
---Prime  Minister // A Person
----State
-----Chief Minister // A Person
------District
-------District Minister // A Person
--------Area
---------Area Minister (AM) // A Person
```

So basically what i am trying to do here is, I want to `Focus` on `Area Minister`. As he will be soul of my application. Others are just the part of hierarchy. So lets say, if I am adding an `Area Minister` then he/she will be under an `Area`, and `Area` is under a `District Minister` and `District Minister` is under `District` and `District` is under `Chief Minister` and `SO ON......`

What I am doing here is adding these details for `Area Minister` into my `MySQL Database` So what i have  done in database is, I have created the following tables:

1. Country // For adding entry
2. President // For adding president in country (So country_id is foreign key here)
3. Central // For adding central under President (So president_id is foreign key here)
4. ...
5. ...
6. ...
7. ...
8. ...
9. Area // For adding area under District manager (So district_manager_id is foreign key here)
10. Area_Minister // For adding Area Minister (AM) in Area (So area_id is foreign key here)

The question is for fetching details of `AM` through `**PHP**`. I am fetching data's from `**MySQL**` and as `AM` is the core data which i am looking for, but the associated data's are also required at some points. But the core is `AM - Data`. However if I am going through this way, I am trying to fetch data's from `10 - TEN TABLES`. Which i feel is pain.

Because to get the required data, I match `Area` ID in `AM`, then `District Minister` ID in `Area` and so on to the start level of hierarchy.

Is there any way that i can do to minimize this process. As the core data which i want is just `AM i.e Area Manager's Data`.

Any way that i can structure it well. Or maybe if any sought of help someone can provide me with insight that if this could be done through stored procedures.

I am just looking for a way to reduce the complexity of code in PHP and So many tables in MySQL, when core data is just there with `AM` only.

Kindly advice.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think ten tables is that many.

Comment: @lc. Actually there are many other tables also. But these tables i have made just for getting details for `Area Manager`, So 9 Tables just for referencing `Area Manager` looks quite costly to me. Just that, So I am looking for you people expert advice and insight over this.

Comment: @lc. The basic problem is, whenever I am fetching details for `Area Manager`, I am required to fetch details from `10 Tables`.

Answer (score 1):

You have the basic table structure correct, and what you specified seems to be a reasonable structure for your table data.  If you want to reduce the number of tables opened when you access an area manager, there are a few things you can do.

1. Use decorators.  You can create an area manager object which loads only the bare minimum data needed when you fetch an area manager.  Add methods to that object that fetch data from other tables and only run their queries when that data is needed.  For example:

   ```
   class AreaManager {

       public function __construct() {
           //do code which loads the basic table data for an area manager
       }

       public function getPresident() {
            // do the SQL needed to load the president from the relational tables
       }

   }
   ```
2. Denormalize your data.  You can run a script periodically which takes your data and puts it into a single table - so you have a structure like this:

   ```
   area_manager_id | country_name | president | prime_minister | etc.
   ```

   This script would have to be updated as you change your relationships but would allow you easy access to your data through a single query.

All that being said, you have set up relational tables the way they are supposed to be used and a 10 table query isn't usually the end of the world.

Answer (score 1):

Your data wont be that bad as long as you index your foreign key and then using joins on what you are fetching will be fine.

In the end is not about your table because your table is properly structured with the proper relation key but rather your indexing optimization and the query that you will run.